# Travis CI and GitLab CI disappointing - Other options for GitHub?

Tags: travis-ci, gitlab-ci

I have started a Django (private) project on GitHub. I'd like that my repo tell me if my unit tests passed or failed to each commit. I know there exists Travis CI, but it is expensive and a service en GitLab, but I use GitHub, so...

What other free services, options could I use with GitHub?

Comment: You can setup a Jenkins server for handling the CI for you.

Answer (score 1):

Travis CI is free for non-private projects.

Else a quick look at google would give you this:
https://github.com/marketplace/category/continuous-integration

- Travis CI
- CircleCI
- AppVeyor
- Percy
- Buddy
- Semaphore

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have a private Repo. What do you suggest?

Comment: I suggest you look again at topics for this forum: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, in particular "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"

Comment: @J.Doe Either pay for it, make your code public or run the CI runner on your own server. These services cost money to run, You wont find a good one for free unless you make your code public

Answer (score 1):

You can run the Gitlab-ci runner locally in Docker or mirror your repository from GitHub to Gitlab if you really want to keep using GitHub.

Gitlab can pull from your GitHub repository each x minutes and automatically run jobs with gitlab-ci, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html for details.